# Outlook Add-in that just directs to a website

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I want to program a simple Outlook add-in that opens a browser and take the user to a specific site.
I've had a look at using [Yeoman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator), but this add-in opens a task pane where I'm just looking to take that single actions.
Is there a simple way to do this?

## EDIT:

I managed to get this done, but I not have the following issue: I have a single button (via Yeoman's generator) that when clicked executes the following:

```
function action(event) {


const message = {
    type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
    message: "Window opened.",
    icon: "Icon.80x80",
    persistent: true,
  };

  // Show a notification message
  window.open("https://myurl.com");
  Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);

  // Be sure to indicate when the add-in command function is complete
  event.completed();
}
```

I get the following error in Outlook itself:

[image]

We deployed the app using the MS 365 admin center, but I'm not sure if there is something additional that I need to do in this case to run the webserver?

Comment: The task pane is represented by a simple html page. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Office.js API that will open a browser window:

```
Office.ui.openBrowserWindow( -- URL string here -- );
```

This will cause the computers default browser to open to the specified URL. You could have a button in the task pane whose handlers calls this method. Alternatively, you could have a custom button on the ribbon that calls a FunctionFile that calls this method.

Comment: I've tried this, but for some reason it keeps telling me it can't reach my add-in and I should check my connection. I don't have any connection issues.. Any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: What is the "it" that is telling you this? Where exactly do you see the error? You should not be passing the URL of the add-in itself to the openBrowserWindow method.

Comment: I'm passing a public URL. The add-in runs, but the message in Outlook itself just tells me it's not reachable. I'll update my question to reflect.

Comment: It looks like you created another SO post about the connection issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71236972/outlook-add-ins-connection-issue. We will follow up on the connection issue using that post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display any web site to the user as a result of the button click or some action on the pane, try doing `window.open('https://yoursite.com')`. This should work if the domain is whitelisted in your manifest. For example:

```
function redirectFunction() {
    window.open("https://othersite.com")
    //window.location.href = "https://othersite.com";
}
```