# Outlook add-ins : Connection issue

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I created an Outlook add-in and posted it using Integrated Apps in the admin center. I created the add-in using [Yeoman](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office). The application status is OK and appears in the Outlook of relevant users, but I get the following error message when trying to execute it's function:

**Apologies for the blur, I can't seem to fix that though my source image is fine**

[image: Error message]

I have the following line in my manifest.xml file calling the function:

```
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
</Action>
```

And I have the following code in that specific function:

```
function action(event) {
  const message = {
    type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
    message: "Web URL opened.",
    icon: "Icon.80x80",
    persistent: true,
  };

  // Show a notification message
  window.open("https://myurl.com");
  Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);

  // Be sure to indicate when the add-in command function is complete
  event.completed();
}

function getGlobal() {
  return typeof self !== "undefined"
    ? self
    : typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? window
    : typeof global !== "undefined"
    ? global
    : undefined;
}

const g = getGlobal();

// The add-in command functions need to be available in global scope
g.action = action;
```

Does anyone know how what could be going wrong here? And how I can fix this to execute the redirect when the button is clicked?

Comment: Try to remove the `window.open("https://myurl.com");` statement from the code.

Comment: The error typically indicates an issue accessing the app.  Double check the <FunctionFile resid="yourResourceId"/> and make sure the url in resid is accessible. With the Yeoman template and NPM start, the url would likely be https://localhost:3000/...

Comment: Thanks @MSFT, what determines where it looks for the webserver? The <SourceLocation> tag in the manifest.xml file?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev that is literally the only code I want to execute haha, so I can't remove it.

Comment: The FunctionFile resid should point to the Resources section that should have a list of Urls <Url id="yourResourceId" DefaultValue="https://..."/>.